# data driven pages, point to ddp index polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I am trying to figure out how to convert points(currently my ddp driver) into polygons that cover the extent of my data frame. The points feature class are often in close proximity to each-other, and I want to make tiles that overlap, so that I can use them to produce annotations for each tile and then query these annotations with tile ID's to prevent overlapping labels from the tiles.  I am not sure of a quick way to accomplish this.  I have thought about just creating book marks for each DDP and running  a script that converts those to tiles, but is seems like there is probably an easier way.

Comment: Are you able to include a picture that shows your current versus desired index and pages?

Comment: Iterate through pages, capture dataframe Extent and update polygon feature class with it. It is arcpy script you can build by finding similar posts on this forum

Comment: That solution is exactly what I was going for thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add geometry attributes to you points
- Buffer them (any size), dissolve type = None
- Define w(idth)  and h(eight)  of your polygon (640 and 480 below)
- Run this field calculator expression on buffer's field Shape (advanced, Python)

## ---------------------------------

```p
def getRectangle(xC,yC,w,h):
    halfW=w/2;halfH=h/2
    LL=arcpy.Point(xC-halfW,yC-halfH)
    UL=arcpy.Point(xC-halfW,yC+halfH)
    UR=arcpy.Point(xC+halfW,yC+halfH)
    LR=arcpy.Point(xC+halfW,yC-halfH)
    array = arcpy.Array([LL,UL,UR,LR])
    return arcpy.Polygon(array)
```

## ----------------------------------

```
getRectangle( !POINT_X!, !POINT_Y!,640,480)
```

to get something like this:

[image]

**Solution tested on shapefiles**